# Como arreglar el error para recuperar un valor de una celda de excel en c#

Tags: c#, excel

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en C# para recuperar valores de varias celdas en Excel pero cuando quiero recuperar el valor me salta el error

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Si recupera el valor pero no deja terminar el programa, se que debe de llevar un

```
try
    {               
        //MyCode
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
    }
```

pero cuando lo pongo ya no recupera el valor en el textbox, como podria solucionarlo.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{
    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnaceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;

        string modulo;

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\N033321a\Desktop\modulos.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
        row = range.Rows.Count;
        column = range.Columns.Count;
        //R,C
        modulo = (range.Cells[4, 6] as Excel.Range).Value;
        txtFecha.Text = modulo.ToString();

        xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
        xlApp.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }
}
```

Donde me salta el error es en la linea de

```
xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la respuesta la comparto, solo era necesario el try y catch de la forma siguiente:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{
public Form1(){
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnaceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    Excel.Range range;
try{
    string modulo;

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\N033321a\Desktop\modulos.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
    row = range.Rows.Count;
    column = range.Columns.Count;
    //R,C
    modulo = (range.Cells[4, 6] as Excel.Range).Value;
    txtFecha.Text = modulo.ToString();

    xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
    xlApp.Quit();

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
   }
}catch(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex){
     xlApp=new Excel.Application();
}}}
```

Ya con eso lo envia perfectamente